# Initialize a struct inside a union (C++)

Tags: c++, x86

I'm creating a very limited, domain-specific x86 assembler in C++ (Visual Studio 2010) that dynamically generates instructions, writes it to memory, and executes it, all at runtime. First I write them to a temporary byte stream, and then write the entire stream to executable memory in one `memcpy`.

I use the following code for constructing a `movsd [imm32], xmm1` instruction:

```
typedef unsigned char byte;
enum SSE2Register;

void WriteValueToMemory(double* dest, SSE2Register source)
{
    union
    {
        struct
        {
            byte insts[4];
            double* dest;
        };

        byte bytes[8];
    } movsd = 
    {
        // movsd [imm32], xmm1
        0xF2, 0x0F, 0x11, // Opcode
        0x05 + (8 * source), // ModR/M 
        dest // imm32
    };

    _stream.Write(movsd.bytes, sizeof(movsd.bytes));
}
```

This code works: the three opcode bytes and the ModR/M byte are written to `insts`, the destination (`imm32`) is written to `dest`, and `bytes` contains the entire instruction in raw bytes, ready to be written to the instruction stream.

However, I am curious as to whether this method of initializing the union is safe/portable. Is it OK to initialize the four values of `insts` and the value of `dest` within a single set of braces?

In other words, is this the *correct, portable* way of doing this, or should I do it a different way?

Thanks!

Comment: That isn't the correct, portable way, but it's very very close.

Comment: BTW: If you want to be consistent with intels manuals and most online resources I'd call probably call it either `movsd m64, xmm` or `s/imm32/disp32`.

Answer (score 2):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2cx9y4f.aspx

> **Anonymous Structures**
>
> A Microsoft C extension allows you to declare a structure variable
>   within another structure without giving it a name. These nested
>   structures are called anonymous structures. C++ does not allow
>   anonymous structures.
>
> You can access the members of an anonymous structure as if they were
>   members in the containing structure.

However, you don't need a `union` for what you're doing.

```
void WriteValueToMemory(double* dest, SSE2Register source)
{
    struct
    {
        byte insts[4];
        double* dest;
    } movsd = 
    {  // movsd [imm32], xmm1
        0xF2, 0x0F, 0x11, // Opcode
        0x05 + (8 * source), // ModR/M 
        dest // imm32
    };

    _stream.Write(&movsd, sizeof(movsd));
}
```

Comment: I like that! The only thing I had to change was the `_stream.Write()` call: I had to cast `&movsd` to `byte*`, since the signature of `Write` is `(byte arr[], int arrSize)`, but it works, and it's portable. Thanks!

Comment: Remember, a anonymous struct is _not_ portable.  If you still have the union, you'll have to name the struct.

Comment: Wouldn't your way of doing it in a single `struct` be C++ compliant, since it is declared as `movsd`? Or would I actually have to declare it as a namespace-wide type to use it in other compilers?

Comment: Yes, my code is portable, since it has a name.  The rule is: "You can't have an unnamed structure inside of another structure/union."